# php как проверить наличие элемента в строке?

Tags: php

Проверяю переменные таким кодом:

```
if($this->item->fcity != 'Москва' && $this->item->fcity != 'Московская область')
```

Но проблема такая что у второго значения может быть не точное значение, а конкретнее после текста Московская область может быть еще что то?

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска в строке можно использовать функцию [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php):

```
if (strpos($this->item->fcity, 'Москва') === 0) {
    echo "Строка начинается с подстроки 'Москва'.";
}

if (strpos($this->item->fcity, 'Московская область') !== false) {
    echo "В строке есть хотя бы одна подстрока 'Московская область'.";
}
```

В обоих условиях используется строгое сравнение так как:

> Эта функция может возвращать как boolean FALSE, так и не-boolean значение, которое приводится к FALSE. За более подробной информацией обратитесь к разделу Булев тип. Используйте оператор === для проверки значения, возвращаемого этой функцией.